# What do you call two consecutive months; a sixth of a year?

Tags: single-word-requests, time, latin, neologisms

Half a year is a *[semester](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/175585)*, i.e. (literally) 6 months. Since it’s often wrongly thought to derive from *semi-* ‘half’, there’re contradicting definitions of similar terms: Both a *[trimester](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/206120)* and a (rare) *quadmester* are either 3 months, i.e. a fourth of a year, or a third of a year, i.e. 4 months. The definitions are mutually exclusive, that means the terms never mean the same duration in the same context. These are academic terms that usually subdivide the academic year from autumn to autumn, not the calendar year. Human pregnancies are also often divided into 3 three-month trimesters.

In economics and accounting, a *quarter* or *quarter-year* is often used, which is either defined as 3 months or as 13 weeks, i.e. 90–92 days. The possible alternative term *fourth* is not being used, as far as I know.

What would you call a sixth part of the calendar year, i.e. 2 collective months or about 60 days?

From other European languages, I’d assume *[sextal](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/177040)*, but the OED only lists ‘base 6’ as a meaning of that word (like ‘octal’) and it’s not *[quartal](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/156018)* (or *[tertial](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/199628)* and *[quintal](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/156695)*) in English but *quart**er*** – alas, *sexter* seems just wrong. Sometimes the Romance *x* becomes an *s*, and *[sester](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/176780)* used to be a (Middle) English measure indeed. 
I could also go Greek (*hexa-*) instead of Latin.

I guess *double-month* or *di-/bi-month* could also work.
A neologism is fine as long as it’s understandable and doesn’t raise wrong associations like a six-month span.

Comment: 3 (consecutive) (calendar) months can equate to 89 days.  Are you saying that 'quarter' is only used with Jan-Feb-Mar etc, or can be used with any 3-month period?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth In my experience, _quarter_ usually subdivides the calendar year, but it’s actually quite possible that it’s also used to partition the tax or fiscal year, which in some legislations can begin any day of the year (and sometimes have just 360 nominal days). _Trimesters_ or _quadmesters_ and _seasons_, on the other hand, are almost never Jan-Feb-Mar, Apr-May-Jun, Jul-Aug-Sep and Oct-Nov-Dec (or 13-week approximations thereof).

Comment: Sometimes two months is just two months.

Comment: IN UK English I've never heard of a word used in that context.  However,  when a magazine is published once every 2 months,  it is referred to as a bi-monthly publication. That's the only similar language usage I can think of.

Comment: I'd be careful about a semester being exactly six months, in colleges it's about four, usually with time off in the summer. It would be very confusing to use semester to refer to a six month period outside the usual semesters beginning in September and January, to an academic audience at least.

Comment: I'm a Portuguese speaker and "bimestre" is a widely used term here used to refer to a period of two months. It's interesting to realize a specific word is not common in the English language, makes me wonder why that would be.
The school year in Brazil is divided in 4 *bimestres*, I assume English-speaking countries would be different, otherwise they'd have a word for it already.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you are looking for the term  ***[bimester](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bimester):***

> - a period of two months

(M-W)

Usage examples:

> In each case they contitute an average of the responses in the October- November  bimester. ([Use of Survey Data for Industry, 1999.](https://books.google.it/books?id=6B0EAQAAIAAJ&q=%22bimester%22&dq=%22bimester%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj38pmF8anLAhUiJJoKHWz5AVY4ChDoAQgjMAE))
>
> We proposed a bimester alternative to the trimester model. ([Undergraduate Projects Linking Science, Technology and Society.](https://books.google.it/books?id=OHNMAAAAYAAJ&q=%22bimester%22&dq=%22bimester%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZ4vSy9KnLAhVrMZoKHXbFA1wQ6AEIVzAJ) )

Comment: Yes, it works, but I would prefer a term for a sixth of a year over one for two months, although that will often be the same.

Comment: @Crissov Are you talking about non-Gregorian calendars, or is there a risk of ambiguity because members of your audience might not adhere to 12-month years? Or is the question of temporal alignment, for example from mid-March to mid-May is a sixth of a year but spans 3 calendar months (though its duration is shorter than any 3 calendar months)? But, then,  all your other examples (quarter, trimester, etc) align to calendar month boundaries. Otherwise, when can a sixth of a year differ from two calendar months? Planets with other periods of revolution?

Comment: @DanBron I’m indeed talking about other calendars, but the Gregorian calendar is of course universally known and thus can serve as a reference. A sixth of a year (almost 61 days) is within the range of lengths of two consecutive months (59 to 62 days), of course, but in my case, the sixths are rounded to full weeks (56 or 63 days). I thought that was a bit too exotic and specific to be put into the question.

Comment: @Crissov: well, if "semester" can be used to refer to half a year even when that doesn't mean six exact months, then "bimester" by analogy could refer to a sixth of a year even when that is not exactly two months.

Comment: This is a 90s term that never caught on. Ngram of bimester and [half of a quarter](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=half+of+a+quarter%2Cbimester&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chalf%20of%20a%20quarter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbimester%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @Mazura - *two-month period * is the more common alternative. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=half+of+a+quarter%2Cbimester%2C+two+month+period&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chalf%20of%20a%20quarter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbimester%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctwo%20month%20period%3B%2Cc0

Comment: This is absolutely technically correct, but the word is so rare it is likely to cause confusion. I would recommend either saying "two months" or providing an explanation of what a bimester is the first time you use it in a document.

Answer (score 3):

In some cases, the simplest solution is "60 days". Or "two months".

(I've never quite understood why we get so many questions seeking single commonly known words for concepts. There is no rule saying such words have to exist, and there is nothing wrong with using a short phrase as, effectively, a compound word. Yes, seeking the perfect word is a fun game, but unless you already know it or are writing poetry, finding it is largely a distraction from actually communicating... And often the best way to find out if simply to "consult the oracular lizard of the ancient lexophile culture" and ask a thesaurus.)

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_prefix), the numerical prefix corresponding to "sixth" is *sextant-* (which seems to be derived from the Latin word for sixth, *sextans*). In fact, I can't find any English word that uses this as a prefix.

But if this is accurate, it suggests the neologism *sextantennium* (sixth of a year) by analogy with words like *millennium* (thousand year period) and *sesquiennium*/*[sesquiennial](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sesquiennial)* (a period of one and a half years/every one and a half years, also mentioned here: [Is there a term to describe an event which happens every 18 months?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28915/is-there-a-term-to-describe-an-event-which-happens-every-18-months)).

I searched for *sextantennium* on Google and found zero results. Personally, I'd go with Josh61's suggestion of *bimester.*

Another related question:

- [word for six-month period.....not as an adjective or as an associated adverb, but as an affirmed set word](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/248567/word-for-six-month-period-not-as-an-adjective-or-as-an-associated-adverb-bu?rq=1)