# Year Division by Quarters: any terms to express halves of years or other parts of years?

Tags: time

Quarters divide years by four. I am looking for the terms dividing years by 2, 3 and 6.

**Does there exists terms to express other parts of the years like quarters?**

Comment: Quarter is a generic term that means "divide in to four parts". It's not year specific, so use the same generic terms for the other fractions.

Comment: @MattE.Эллен I cannot understand. Can I refer to half of year by Q1 and the second half of year by Q2? How does the reader know to which part of the year I mean?

Comment: Downvoters would be recommended to be more constructive and leave a comment for improvement.

Comment: Why would you refer to halves as quarters?

Comment: @MattE.Эллен I thought you meant this by `[quarter]'s not year specific, so use the same generic terms for the other fractions` where quarter is the generic term?

Comment: No, I mean that you can say "this is the first quarter of my apple" or "this is the second quarter of my pie". It's not specific to years. So you can use the generic term for each fraction.

Comment: @MattE.Эллен I want to describe year by halves, trichotomy, quarters, five parts, six parts and so forth -- there exist no english term for each specific part?

Comment: Half, third, fifth, etc.

Comment: Q1 means first quarter.  It is often used in business, when the year is divided into four parts for bookkeeping.  The other quarters are Q2, Q3, and Q4.  I have not seen H1 for first half, nor T1 for first third.

Comment: @GEdgar I have seen H1/H2 - rarely But you'd want to explain them at first use in each document until they became established in context

Comment: Related question for 1/6 year or 2 months: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/311736/what-do-you-call-two-consecutive-months-a-sixth-of-a-year

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, a ***quarter***, or ***trimester*** is a period of 3 months (a quarter year).

> Quarter: one fourth of a calendar or fiscal year:
>   The bank sends out a statement each quarter.(http://www.dictionary.com/browse/quarter)
>
> Trimester: a period of three or about three months; especially :any of three periods of approximately three months each into which a human pregnancy is divided https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trimester

A ***semester*** is a period of six months (half a year).

> Semester :a period of six months https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/semester

A ***bimester*** is a sixth of a year (two months).

> Bimester :a period of two months

A ***tertile*** or ***quadrimester*** is four months (a third of a year).

> Quadrimester: A period of four months http://www.definition-of.com/quadrimester
>
> Tertile: 1. (statistics) Either of the two points that divide an ordered distribution into three parts, each containing a third of the population.
>   2. (statistics) Any one of the three groups so divided.
>   *The first tertile results include January through April's revenues*. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tertile

Comment: @hhh: to address the comment you added to your question- there are no other common terms in English for fractions of a year, like 1/5 year, 1/8 year, etc

Comment: The above aren't all commonly used, either. [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=semester%2Ctrimester%2Cbimester%2Cquadrimester%2Ctertile&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csemester%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctrimester%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbimester%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cquadrimester%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctertile%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth ... true, scratch 'other' in my last comment :) +1

Comment: @ArchContrarian the others divide the year into whole months (thus aren't really fractions if you think of the number of days). Fifths and eighths wouldn't, and would be of very limited use

Comment: @ChrisH ... that's true, but the question asks for words like 'quarter'. A quarter is invariably a period of three calendar months - not 1/4  of the days in the year. (Most years have a number of days not divisible by 4, anyway). Also, a 'fraction' can mean any part or subset, not just a precise arithmetical fraction.

Comment: @ArchContrarian *fraction* carries the meaning of *part*. *Quarter* can too, especially as areas of cities, but 3 months is a quarter of the months in a year. *Half* can be very imprecise but still means division into two. Generally other fractions  have the same meaning in everyday use as their mathematical meaning, with a margin of error. *Eighth* could just about mean a period of 6 weeks, but you'd have some left at the end of the year. I just can't see it working (or fifth, with ten weeks)

Comment: @ChrisH ... I see what you're getting at now. You're correct.

Comment: @ArchContrarian Fiscal and statistical quarters can also be defined as normally 91 days or 13 weeks and exceptionally 92 days or 14 weeks (98 days), cf. [Apple's 2012Q4 reporting fiasco](http://www.businessinsider.com/calendar-reform-for-public-companies-2013-3). Also, if you'd accept _tertile_ for 4 months or 1/3 year, _quartile_ for 3 months or 1/4 year and _sextile_ for 2 months or 1/6 year would be the systematic consequence. There was a measure of beverage casks called a _tertian_ which is 1/3 tun.

Answer (score 1):

In American business usage, particularly in financial reports, the year is divided into either months or quarters. No other division is common enough to have been given a name except for half. "That merger is scheduled to close in the first half."

"Semester" and "trimester" are primarily, perhaps exclusively, academic terms and refer to divisions of a "school year," which is not generally 365 days. I cannot remember hearing those terms ever used in a commercial or financial context.

It is of course possible to find special terms, but they are not in frequent use. What is usually done is to specify a fraction of a year or a number of days, weeks, or months. One might say "a third of a year" or "four months." Fractions using sixths or twelfths are rare. Most would say "seven months" rather than "seven twelfths of a year."

Comment: **"Semester" and "trimester" are primarily, perhaps exclusively, academic terms** Well, "trimester" is also used for pregnancies.

Comment: @ GEdgar. True but perhaps confusing with references to divisions of the solar year. "Trimester" in the obstetrical sense stands for one third of the duration of a normal human pregnancy, which is about three months, which is a quarter of a year. I should have said that "trimester" is primarily used in a certain restricted contexts to represent a third of a period, but it is seldom if ever used to designate a third of a solar year. Nevertheless, I overstated my case.